# Using a Jetty server causes the doGet() method to be called twice in my servlet

Tags: servlets, jetty

I am using a [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) server to run on my local host using an Eclipse plugin.

My URL request is in the form

```
http://localhost:8080/TestServer/Project/?Action=5
```

When I call this method, my `doGet` method is calling twice in the servlet. I am not implementing either the `doPost` method or the `Service` method. I am just using it, but for a single HTTP request, it's calling the `doGet` method of the servlet twice run.

Why is a single URL is causing to run twice?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Print("In doGet method");
}
```

Comment: is that exactly your doGet method, or have you edited it?

Comment: no i havent edited this is the original doGet method

Comment: well, something is making two requests and you don't indicate what sort of client your using, is it a web browser, the browser built into eclipse, or an http client library?  that or your jetty handler chain is configured wrong but hard to say since you don't mention if it is embedded jetty or a jetty distribution or...

Comment: i have used run jun run plugin in eclipse...and i am trying it via a browser, and running the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raghul, if doGet is called twice, there's only one probable conclusion: there are 2 requests coming.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Implement doGet and inspect the HttpServletRequest object, see if there's any difference between the object supplied by the web container in the two calls.
2. Use [tcpmon](https://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/) and inspect the data transmitted over the wire. Nothing to install, you can run it directly online. You'll see the headers there and you want to pay special attention to the field **User-Agent**. Chances are, it will not be the same for both calls. If it's exactly the same, your browser is the only culprit and I suggest you try with a different one or reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to track the sent HTTP request with your browser (if you use Chrome, use the Network tabs of the developer tools).

In my case I had the same problem and I discover the reason by tracking HTTP request. Perhaps you have the same case than me. I used the Chrome JSONView Extension and when I access to an URL which returns JSON content, twice HTTP request was send (Browser URL + JSONView which send AJAX request (content.js))